# How to add margins to horizontal panels in bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a set of 3 horizontal panels. I want to add some padding inbetween each panel so it looks better.. Here is what it looks like currently. [image]

Here is my html

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">


<div class="col-md-4 panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Eating Healthy</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p class="panel-content">
      Hello, it's me. I was wondering, if after all these years you'd like to meet. To go over everything. They say that time's supposed to heal ya. But i ain't done much healing. Hello. Can you hear me? I'm in California. Dreamin about who we used to be, when we were young and free.
    </p>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="col-md-4 panel panel-default ">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Health Calculators</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p class="panel-content">
      Hello, it's me. I was wondering, if after all these years you'd like to meet. To go over everything. They say that time's supposed to heal ya. But i ain't done much healing. Hello. Can you hear me? I'm in California. Dreamin about who we used to be, when we were young and free.
    </p>  </div>
</div>


  <div class="col-md-4 panel panel-default ">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Health and Awareness</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p class="panel-content">
        Hello, it's me. I was wondering, if after all these years you'd like to meet. To go over everything. They say that time's supposed to heal ya. But i ain't done much healing. Hello. Can you hear me? I'm in California. Dreamin about who we used to be, when we were young and free.
      </p>    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried "margin-outside: 10%" in my application.css.scss but that did nothing to add padding between the panels. I'm not quite sure how to fix this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the panel classes in the same div that has the col classes.

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
<div class="panel panel-default ">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Health Calculators</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p class="panel-content">
          Hello, it's me. I was wondering, if after all these years you'd like to meet. To go over everything. They say that time's supposed to heal ya. But i ain't done much healing. Hello. Can you hear me? I'm in California. Dreamin about who we used to be, when we were young and free.
        </p>  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/Bri4UcQ7Zi